# SQL VERTICA running sums 30/60/90 days

Tags: sql, database, vertica

Hi I have two tables with many to many relationships

[image]

and as results I want for every record in scoring table (so id_case and id_date) I would like to see sum of transactions from scoring.id_date to scoring.id_date+30 days , +60 days etc.

This is what I came up so far but its not working at all:

```
  with t as  (select id_case,id_date,amount 
                    from TableTransactions 
                     ) 


            SELECT id_case,f.id_date,
                   sum(case when exists (select * from t t where t.id_case=f.id_case and t.id_date between f.id_date and (to_char(date(cast( f.id_date as varchar(8))) + 360, 'YYYYMMDD'))::int ) then t.amount else 0 end )  as Days360

            from TableScoring f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a `join` with conditional aggregation:

```
select s.id_case, s.id_date,
       sum(case when t.id_date >= s.id_date and t.id_date < s.id_date + interval '30 day'
                then t.amount else 0
           end) as amount_30,
       sum(case when t.id_date >= s.id_date and t.id_date < s.id_date + interval '60 day'
                then t.amount else 0
           end) as amount_60,
       sum(case when t.id_date >= s.id_date and t.id_date < s.id_date + interval '90 day'
                then t.amount else 0
           end) as amount_90
from scoring s join
     transactions t
     on t.id_case = s.id_case
group by s.id_case, s.id_date;
```

Comment: Gordon i think it wont work as there are multiple scoring rows. So lets say we have 2 scores for 1 id_case with different scoring dates.would join and then aggregate generate duplicate rows ?

Comment: @rafalbballer . . . This should work, at least in the sense that it produces a separate row for each scoring date.  You can remove the date from the `group by` and `select` and it will work overall.